# Why do I have two different screens for the same action in Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

I'm trying to change the way users log into Windows XP, but when I click on User Accounts in Control Panel, I get different screens on different machines, though they are both Windows XP Professional SP3.

Here's the first screen: 
[image]

Here's the second screen:
[image]

What do I have to do to see the first screen on the second machine?

References:

1. [Microsoft's Fast User Switch on Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279765/en-us)

Comment: Confirm if they are both with Service Pack 3. And check if you are using the same theme/skin for Windows. It looks like theme is different - classic view in the first and XP look on the second. I would point at this as the source of differences.

Comment: Service Pack 3 on both confirmed.

Comment: Here's the screen with the same theme/skin applied: same results (different screens). http://cativaimagem.com.br/temp/windows_Xp_screen_01_new.jpg

Comment: found the answer... sorry wasting you guys time: Found the answer here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294739/en-us (bold is mine)

> This feature is only available **if the computer is not a member of a Microsoft Windows NT, Windows 2000, or Microsoft Windows Server 2003 domain**, and you are not using a third-party product that replaces the Microsoft Graphical Identification and Authentication file (Msgina.dll).

The computer on screen 1 has not yet been added to the domain, while the one on screenshot 2 has been. 

p.s.: can't answer for the next 7 hours. :)